# IIS configuration setting or web.config setting to terminate any long pending requests process under worker process

Tags: .net, forms, iis, web

I am working on a public facing application developed using .NET 4.5.1 framework as a WebForm Application.

We are experiencing application slowness from time to time and when we investigated the issue we saw that there are requests hanging on application pool for long time period.

We have defined application pool queue length as 1000 and setup 120 seconds as connection time out under Limits

Is there any IIS configuration setting or web.config setting to terminate any long pending requests process under worker process?

We have Windows 2012 R2 with IIS 8.0

Also this application uses "in-proc" as session management. 
We have set **compilation debug="false"** and **trace enabled="false"** in production envirnment

Any solution please

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that is your very issue, but after a period of inactivity IIS temporarily stops the ApplicationPool to save resources. If the startup time of your app is quite long-ish and it has not been accessed for a period of time, it may well occur that you experience hangs in that case.

**Overcome the issue**

You can disable the AppPool being recycled due to inactivity. From the IIS Manager select your AppPool. In the *actions* pane there should be an item Recycling. This will open a dialog where you can change the settings when a AppPool will be recycled. The default should be after a period of time, but there are other options as well.

[Further Reading about AppPool Recycling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: The issue is that some requests are running for a long time. This could be caused by a lot of possible problems, like infinite cycles, using slow APIs, having slow algorithms and so on and so on and so on. Naturally, ApplicationPool stopping can be disabled, which could be good for the op, but does not really address the issue unless we assume that the slowness comes from here, therefore I think your answer should be more of a comment until we find out for sure that this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need this as a part of your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

This way you set the limit in seconds. However, your requests that will time out might be important, so I believe you should optimize them, get rid of infinite cycles and so on. As about the limit you were asking for, you can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot. I have already include the following in web.config  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="32768" executionTimeout="120" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>

Comment: @HarindaLakmal I see. Under IIS 7 you can configure an application pool to be recycled when its CPU usage stays above a certain treshold for a certain period of time, using Application Pools -> Select Pool -> Advanced -> CPU